# Loading icon while less modifyVars is compiling

Tags: javascript, css, less

I am using **window.less.modifyVars(modified_variables);** on the front-end to reflect the changes. And i want to show **loading icon** while less is compiling. Is there any way to check that less has started compilation and completed.

Comment: the `modifyVars` returns a promise, but neither `then` or `done` are called... could you try `window.less.modifyVars(modified_variables).done(function() { console.log('modifyVars done'); });` and see if it works?

Comment: uhmm... I found this https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1957 but I couldn't make it work either. I suggest that you open a issue in their repository.

Answer (score -1):

In the less.js GitHub repo I referred to how they use modifyVars() in their [test spec](https://github.com/less/less.js/blob/9d3ef59cf818691cd52410879e7152e7d589de32/test/browser/runner-modify-vars-spec.js). You could show the loading icon, call the modifyVars method and then using .then(), hide the loading icon.

```
// Show loading icon

less.modifyVars({
    var1: "green",
    var2: "purple",
    var3: 20
}).then(function () {

    // Hide loading icon
    done();
});
```